# No such table found SQLITE Error

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

`SQLiteOpenHelper` class

```
public class DataDB extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Datas";
    private static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES =
            "CREATE TABLE " + FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                    FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                    FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_NAME + " TEXT," +
                    FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_DESC + " TEXT," +
                    FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_IMG_URL + " TEXT," +
                    FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PRICE + " TEXT);";

    private static final String SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES =
            "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME;

    public DataDB(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        Log.e("Syntax",SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES);
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES);
        onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDowngrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        onUpgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
    }

}
```

Code to insert content

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

values.put(FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_ID, Integer.parseInt(oneObject.getString("id")));
values.put(FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_NAME, oneObject.getString("name"));
values.put(FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_DESC, oneObject.getString("desc"));
values.put(FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_IMG_URL, oneObject.getString("img_url"));
values.put(FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PRICE, oneObject.getString("price"));

db.insert(FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
```

Error message

```
10-12 23:20:05.244 19171-19171/com.dkartindia.dkart E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such table: category
10-12 23:20:05.250 19171-19171/com.dkartindia.dkart E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting name=VEGETABLES0 price=20.00 description=King prawns are the most popular species of prawn in Australia, due no doubt to their rich flavour and moist flesh. img_url=http://www.dkartindia.com/image.jpg id=0
                                                                      android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: category (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO category(name,price,description,img_url,id) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)
                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:898)
                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:509)
                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1499)
                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1371)
                                                                          at com.dkartindia.dkart.Activities.Home$2.onResponse(Home.java:114)
                                                                          at com.dkartindia.dkart.Activities.Home$2.onResponse(Home.java:85)
                                                                          at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.deliverResponse(JsonRequest.java:65)
                                                                          at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5717)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
```

Comment: `no such table: category` table name not found .

Comment: Yes i know that. But category table is not creating. 
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "category"; @IntelliJAmiya

Comment: Same problem if you uninstall app ? and run once again .

Comment: Yes i tried that @IntelliJAmiya

Comment: for test case `DATABASE_NAME = "Data.db"` . Uninstall and run

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Again same problem.

Comment: For test case   SET `TABLE_NAME` instead of `FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya But that does not effect the code right. I have output the Query String CREATE TABLE category (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,name TEXT,description TEXT,img_url TEXT,price TEXT); there is no syntax error in that

Comment: Add extra space `TABLE_NAME + " (  " + ` . You should add `SPACE` .

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Still the same

Comment: Change DATABASE version to 2 then run the app then change again to 1

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Tried but still the same problem.

Comment: `db.insert("category", null, values);`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Still not

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html I have followed the same method

Comment: @SushinPv cool ! Kindly check https://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Comment: sloppy mistake coming .

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya At last i found the problem. Somewhere on my code there was a drop command. That's why after creating the table it is droping. Thank you for helping me out.

Comment: indeed indeed . Move ahead ,

Comment: @SushinPv As per SO rule , Please answer and own accept please .

Comment: Absolutely. Thank you @IntelliJAmiya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in my code there was a `Drop Command`. That's why after creating the table it was dropping. By removing the lines solved my problem.

Comment: Glad to see you fixed that .